# Handling custom JavaScript asynchronous events

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

We have a JavaScript library that lives between 2 proprietary libraries in JavaScript (lib_Upper and lib_Lower). Our library translates returns from lib_Lower to the values/functions lib_Upper is expecting - i.e.

```
lib_Upper  ->  lib_US  -> lib_Lower
```

lib_Lower runs in an asynchronous way, but does not return promises or other deferred objects. Likewise lib_Upper acts as if everything is synchronous.

Hence, we need to convert to async to sync calls.

The process of calls is such:

```
lib_Upper calls lib_US.fn()
lib_US calls lib_lower.fn2()
lib_Lower sends the request over a WebSocket and returns
```

At this point everything bubbles back up to lib_Upper.

Some time later a response returns from the WebSocket:

```
lib_Lower calls lib_US.callbackFn()
lib_US library needs to return the data from lib_lower to lib_Upper
```

At this point we are stuck as we have already returned to lib_Upper.

Being quite new to JavaScript, it is looking quite difficult to "suspend" the call from lib_Upper until the callback occurs.

How do we get to an asynchronous event into this chain such that lib_Upper is only returned the data from the callback?

Thanks.

Comment: then make your library return promises..

Comment: We can't change lib_Upper or lib_Lower. We are limited to being stuck in the middle doing the translation.

Comment: http://librakblog.blogspot.in/2013/08/call-ajax-after-completion-of-another.html
May be this link helps you.

Comment: If lib_Upper neither supports promises nor callbacks, you just have to switch to another library if you need asynchronous behaviour. If you would be more concrete about the libraries and calls, we might can help you with the conversion.

Comment: Can't - it is proprietary and it implements customer and business logic required by the client and the client has mandated the use of both libraries, that's why we are stuck in the middle.

Comment: Tell your client that this is impossible then. If you could be more specific about the libraries and show their codes, me might find a hacky workaround though (like using SJAX)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the process you should be able to pass everything Lib_Upper is doing after Lib_Lower's callback like so:

```
libLower(someArgs, function(data) { libUpper.bar(translator(data)); })
```

Comment: Thanks - but not how this would actually work? libUpper would need a function "bar", whereas what they are doing is calling libUS and expecting a synchronous response while libLower is doing an asynchronous operation.